# it is incomprehensible for me to

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitives

> a. It is incomprehensible for me to treat one's wife the way Tom does.
>
> b. For me it is incomprehensible to treat one's wife the way Tom does.
>
> c. For me, it is incomprehensible to treat one's wife the way Tom does.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

The idea is: I can't understand why Tom treats his wife in the way he does. His treatment of his wife is incomprehensible for me.

Comment: It's incomprehensible to me the way Tom treats his wife.

Answer (score 1):

> a. It is incomprehensible for me to treat one's wife the way Tom does.

> b. For me it is incomprehensible to treat one's wife the way Tom does.

> c. For me, it is incomprehensible to treat one's wife the way Tom does.

The difference between the two prepositional phrases, *to me* and *for me*, is shown below.

*to me* means in my opinion.

*for me* means the matter perhaps will impact me in some way.

As this matter is more to do with your opinion, I suggest we use *to me*.

I also suggest some minor changes, as shown.

> It is incomprehensible to me that someone can treat his wife the way Tom does.

Further explanations on the differences between the two phrases are found in

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/expressing-an-opinion-to-me-or-for-me